# Polynomial growth of L-function

Tags: complex-analysis, modular-forms, mellin-transform

Let $f$ be a newform, $L(f,s)$ the related L-function with Ramanujan-Petersson conjunction $|\lambda(n)|\leq \sigma_0(n)$ (divisor counting function). How can I see that it grows only polynomially in vertical direction in any strip, especially the critical strip $0\leq \Re(s)\leq 1$? My idea was to use the Mellin transform and get
$$|L(f,s)|=\int_0^\infty |L(f,t)|t^{s-1} \,dt\leq \int_0^\infty \bigg|\sum_{n\geq1}\sigma_0(n)n^{-t}\bigg|t^{\Re(s)-1} \,dt.$$

Answer (score 1):

The prototypical way to bound polynomial growth in the critical strip is to use the [Phragmén–Lindelöf Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phragm%C3%A9n%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_principle#Phragm%C3%A9n%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_principle_for_a_sector_in_the_complex_plane). In many other places, this is referred to as the *Convexity Principle*, and bounds coming from it are called *Convexity bounds*.

Now that you know the names of the methods, it's straightforward to find several various proofs using these methods for these convexity bounds.